# subclass NSWindowController Core Data

Tags: core-data, subclass, nswindowcontroller

I have a newb question, which I have tried unsuccessfully to find answers for on the web.  The task is simple: I want to create a core data document-based app but alter the values in some label objects.  Using interface builder, I can build the core data model and populate it, using an array controller, table, etc. all without writing any code.  So far so good.  My test example is to build a core data model with Box entities that have length and width attributes.  I would like a label to display the area, i.e. length*width for any geometrically challenged :).

So after browsing around, I've decided I need to create an NSWindowController subclass and use that to update the label when a box in the table is selected.  Have attempted this, but have failed.  Before I even hook up the label to the window controller, I have a problem.  Following the template comments, I added this to Document.m:

```
- (void)makeWindowControllers
{
    NSLog(@"Adding custom Window Controller");
    MyWindowController* myWindowController = [[MyWindowController alloc] init];
    [self addWindowController:myWindowController];
}
```

Also added this to the template MyWindowController.m:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowController"];
    return self;
}
```

The window controller has its own NIB file from Interface builder where I put the table and label etc.  The file owner is set to MyWindowController.  Probably forgetting other things, but that's what I remember for now.

The log message appears at startup, but then I get an exception "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key managedObjectContext" before the window appears.  I'm guessing that I don't have the window controller hooked up to the document class properly?  My other thought is that the array controller is in the window controller nib, not the document nib, so maybe it's looking in the wrong place for the managedObjectContext?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different approach: Add `area` to your `Box` entity as a read-only attribute. Auto-create a `Box` class with Xcode ("Create NSManagedObject Subclass" menu item in the "Editor" menu when viewing the data model), then add this to Box.h

```
@property (weak, readonly) NSString * area;
```

and this to Box.m

```
- (NSNumber *)area
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([[self length] doubleValue] - [[self width] doubleValue])];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingArea
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"length", @"width", nil];
}
```

If you do this you can just bind `area` to a label value like you do for the other `Box` properties. No need to subclass `NSWindowController` or watch for changes.